# jQuery.support.ajax returns true even if XMLHTTP support is disabled

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I want to detect if AJAX is disabled in the browser. I am using `jQuery.support.ajax` to detect is AJAX is disabled. But, in case of Internet Explorer 8, even if `Enable native XMLHTTP Support` is unchecked in the settings, `jQuery.support.ajax` returns `true` but AJAX actions are not actually happening in the browser.

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here. Any help is highly appreciated. Any other alternative to detect if AJAX is disabled is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the IE8 setting only disables the W3C standard `XMLHttpRequest` object.

It leaves the ActiveX `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` control enabled.  There is a separate setting to disable (all) ActiveX controls.

The jQuery `support.ajax` test works for both methods, so disabling the former but leaving the latter enabled will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to detect if either of them is disabled? Since AJAX actions does not work even if `Enable native XMLHTTP Support` alone is disabled..

Comment: @JSWorld you'd have to be sure that they're not failing for some other reason, first.

Comment: Yes.. When I uncheck `Enable native XMLHTTP Support`, it does not work and when I check `Enable native XMLHTTP Support`, it works fine.